# Immigration at Chicago or Pittsburgh

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india, british-airways, chicago

I am traveling from Delhi to London to Chicago to Pittsburgh via British Airways. I have a terminal change at Chicago airport and have a 2-hour window to do so. Will my immigration take place in Chicago or in Pittsburgh? Moreover, if I miss my flight, will the carrier British Airways provide me another flight to Pittsburgh or will it be my responsibility.

Comment: For clarity, did you book one ticket with connections?

Comment: The first part is a direct duplicate of an existing question (immigration and customs at the US is always at the place you first enter the country). The second part is separate and we need more information.

Comment: If it's in one booking, they'll get you on the next flight, otherwise no